# Full-width images without using background property

Tags: css, image, width

I'm trying to set up a basic portfolio using wordpress as a cms, different post for each project etc.

I'd like the images to fill the screen width (fluidly, so will scale on resize) but without using the background url property, as this is leading to very messy code and crops I don't want

A simple class width 100% image width 100% is working for sizes below the actual image dimensions, but when the screen is larger than the image, it's not filling it.

Is there a way to force the image larger than its native resolution (I know this will screw with the quality) without resorting to the background URL?

Comment: `<img src="blabla.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">` is doing exactly what you have described - it fills its container while stretching/shrinking the image. Or do you want to *repeat* the image rather than *stretching* it?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit vague in that question. I'd like the image to retain its proportions (so I'm using width=100% height=auto)

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or post URL of your site where the problem can be seen?

Comment: http://www.alexanderecob.com/architectural-review/

Comment: Sorry, keep forgetting hitting enter posts the comment: the images scale perfectly well when reducing the window size, but they only scale up to their native resolution, so when the window is larger than a certain point they don't fill. I'm messing around a bit with the background url property but I'm trying to keep as little code in the 'posts' as I can, ideally it would just be img src lines

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your images don't scale-up is the following rule in your CSS:

```
img, object, embed 
{
  max-width: 1140px;
}
```

Either:

- Remove this rule, or
- Exclude the `img` selector from this rule, or
- Leave the above rule as it is and redefine `max-width` to `none` by including an additional rule only for those images which need to scale-up, e.g.:

  ```
  .wrapper>p>img 
  {
    max-width: none;
  }
  ```

Comment: Perfect, I thought I'd caught every max-width instance, completely overlooked this one. Feel a bit of a tit now, thanks for the help!